# Async/Await HttpClient request

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, httpclient

I have a next code in a class, this class gets data from server in XML format:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace TestProj.WebServiceModels
{
public class MyClient
{
     async public static Task<string> fetchContentAsync()
    {
        string url = "https://blabla.com/test/data?format=xml";
        HttpClientHandler aHandler=new HttpClientHandler();
        aHandler.ClientCertificateOptions=ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
        HttpClient aClient=new HttpClient(aHandler);
        Uri requestUri=new Uri(url);
        HttpRequestMessage request=new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
        var result=await aClient.GetAsync(requestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        var responseHeader=result.Headers;
        var responseBody=await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBody;        
    }
}
}
```

On my Main Page i have a function that triggers get method AND IT FAILS!!!:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        fillChartsObject();
    }

private async void fillChartsObject()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await MyClient.fetchContentAsync();
            responseString = response.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            var dlg = new MessageDialog("You are totaly screwed!");
            dlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

**But when i do it on Button click it runs! How can that be?! How to fix it?**

When it fails - it doesn't ask me which certificate to use, in other - does;

Error:
    The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException не обработано пользовательским кодом
HResult=-2146233088
Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SaC.WebServiceModels.MyClient.<fetchContentAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\C5195923\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SaC\SaC\WebServiceModels\MyClient.cs:line 31
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SaC.MainPage.<fillChartsObject>d__96.MoveNext() in c:\Users\foma\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SaC\SaC\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 1546
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   Source=System
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   InnerException:
```

**CODE 2:**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        fillChartsObject();
    }



 private async void fillChartsObject()
    {

        String responseString = "";
            var response = await MyClient.fetchContentAsync();
            responseString = response.ToString();

    }
```

**ERRORS:**

```
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException не обработано пользовательским кодом
   HResult=-2146233088
   Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SAPSalesCentral.WebServiceModels.MyClient.<fetchContentAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\C5195923\Desktop\NewNewRevision\SAPSalesCentral\SAPSalesCentral\WebServiceModels\MyClient.cs:line 31
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SAPSalesCentral.MainPage.<fillChartsObject>d__94.MoveNext() in c:\Users\foma\Desktop\NewNewRevision\SAPSalesCentral\SAPSalesCentral\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 1539
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   Source=System
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   InnerException:
```

Additional functions:

```
ShowLoadingScreen(); // displays semi-transparent background over the whole form and progressRing (native Windows 8 spinner) on it.
GetSettings(); //gets data from local settings storage;
CheckFileExists(); // ASYNC! Checks if data is already stored on a device, if not, gets from web
fillListBox(); // Just populates listbox with hardcoded data;
PopulateHelpMenu(); // Just populates listbox with hardcoded data;
(App.Current as App).Main = this;
```

**Edit:**

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //#region Initialization
        ShowLoadingScreen();
        //fillChartsObject();
        GetSettings();
        CheckFileExists();
        fillListBox();
        PopulateHelpMenu();
        (App.Current as App).Main = this;
        //#endregion
    }


 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await fillChartsObject(); 
        //await fillChartsObject();
        //fillChartsObject();
        ////dtm = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        ////dtm.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
        ////SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += BlankPage_CommandsRequested;
    }

         private async void CheckFileExists()
    {
        //vpnAvailability = await VPN.Check(); //When i uncoment this - it fails again. This just sends request to a link, if it fails = no VPN if not = is VPN.
        ro = new List<RootObject>();
        StorageFile File;
        try
        {
            #region If file exists
            File = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("UserData.txt");
            if (File != null)
            {
                string JSON = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(File);
                if (JSON != "")
                {
                    //If file exists get data
                    try
                    {
                        ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JSON);
                        fillGamificationLine(ro);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        getGamificationDataFromServer();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //If file doesn't exist - get data from server
            getGamificationDataFromServer();
        }
    }

 //The idea was that when all UserData is being populated from server or locally, the request of table data (only from service) is being proceeded parallel.
```

**Thanks to Kris Vandermotten i have ran into this magic:**

**Fails:**

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await fillChartsObject(); 
    }
```

**Works:**

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        await fillChartsObject(); 
    }
```

Comment: I would assume that this "asking for a certificate" requires the UI to have been setup already. Calling it in the constructor of your first page just might be too early.

Comment: And which event should i use when all UI is loaded? Form_Loaded()?

Comment: Instead of calling it in the constructor, try calling it in `protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)`.

Comment: Already tried that - fails

Comment: it displays InnerException:null

Comment: Does using `OnNavigatedTo` fail with the same exception, or a different one?

Comment: Wait a second, trying this one

Comment: Added CODE 2 to my question

Comment: Just to confirm that it is a timing issue, try this: `protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) { await Task.Sleep(500); await fillChartsObject(); }`. If this ugly code works, we can try to find a better solution.

Comment: Ok, now it works. But when i turn on other functions - it fails again.
My other function consist of many other async operations, like reading from data file to display it in UI

Comment: I have modified my question with functions which are being called in MainPage() function. And now i know that it fails when i do my CheckFileExists

Comment: Did you "turn those on" in the constructor, or in OnNavigatedTo, and in the latter case, before or after the calls that were there already?

Comment: See my edit, and the idea of this

Comment: This thing in CheckFileExists() - vpnAvailability = await VPN.Check();
Makes request crash

Comment: Look at my edit at Thanks to Kris Vandermotten... You can comment this, i would be really interested in it. After a few minutes i will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a timing issue, where your code runs too early. You should let the UI initialisation code complete first.

Try this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // allow other queued messages to be processed first
    // this may work as well: await Task.Yield();
    await Task.Delay(1);
    // now continue
    await fillChartsObject();
}

private async void fillChartsObject()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await MyClient.fetchContentAsync();
        responseString = response.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        var dlg = new MessageDialog("You are totally screwed!");
        dlg.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```